# Is it possible to set signatures for each approved "send mail as" through the Google Apps Email Settings API?

Tags: google-email-settings-api

I have a Google Apps account with two others approved "Send mail as" accounts. In the Gmail settings (web interface) I can set one signature for each of the three email addresses.

Is it possible to do the same through the Googe Apps Email Settings API so that I can automate this for the entire organization?

The API documentation (https://developers.google.com/google-apps/email-settings/#manage_signature_settings) does only mention how to define username, but gives no options for specifying the actual email address for that username to set the signature for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not currently possible, no. The Email Settings API only supports setting the signature for the primary email address.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are some 3rd-party apps that can do this but - and it's a big one - it depends on what program you're sending the mail from.

If you're using Outlook, you can use Exclaimer Signature Manager. The point of that software is to control every user's email signature. You could give them multiple signatures to choose from, thus, deciding which one they need based on their 'Send From' setting.

There are other apps, but I don't think any of them do that.

And if you're emailing in a browser, you're out of luck. I don't know if Exclaimer have or are working on a Google Apps-dedicated product, it may be worth checking.

Answer (score 0):

The newer [Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/) allows setting per-address signatures.  See the ["Aliases and signatures" guide](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/alias_and_signature_settings).  Only service accounts that have been delegated domain-wide authority can update signatures for non-primary addresses.